# Jersey Get DIGEST or Basic HTTP Authentication User and Password

Tags: java, jersey, basic-authentication, digest-authentication

How can I get the user and password in request in Jersey 2.4?

The client request sets user and password as below

```
protected HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.universalBuilder()
              .credentialsForBasic("user", "123456") //these are not in header
              .credentials("adminuser", "hello")
              .build();

WebTarget loginTarget = webTarget.path("u").path("login");
loginTarget.register(feature);
ReturnMessage bean = loginTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(..
```

**[Added]** More research suggests that those values can be got in http header in JERSEY1.x, but not in 2.x